# Как вытащить минимальную сумму с сайта на JAVA?

Tags: java, парсер

К примеру есть некоторая торговая площадка. На ней какая то страница с закупкой. К примеру вот эта:
https://market.otc.ru/ProductRequestGroup/Index/533468

Задача: Найти в нижней части самую меньшую сумму оферты поставщика и вернуть это значение. В данном случае - 142800 р. И вывести в консоль только эту сумму.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://market.otc.ru/ProductRequestGroup/Index/533468");

        try {
            LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String s1 = reader.readLine();
                    while (s1 != null) {
                       s1 = reader.readLine();

                      if (s1 != null) gdeMoney(s1);
                    }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void gdeMoney(String testingString) {
    if (testingString.contains("руб")) {
        Pattern pat= Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?");
        Matcher matcher=pat.matcher(testingString);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Это не фриланс площадка.

Comment: Ну это и понятно. Я только начал изучать java, пока сильно плаваю в вопросах. Думал что здесь можно получить ответы на вопросы.

Comment: Разбей задучу на подзадачи. Посути, ты сформулировал задачу. Но в таком виде её никто просто так решать не будет. 1) Тебе нужно получить HTML-контент страницы. 2) тебе нужно распарсить этот контент. 3) в распарсенном контенте нужно найти  нужную таблицу, столбец, и минимальное значение в столбце. 4) нужно вывести сумму в консоль. Что конкретно у тебя не получается?

Comment: я получил вывод HTML-контента в консоль и теперь вот застрял. Не пойму как зацепиться за нужный столбец с цифрами. Найти минимум это потом не проблема конечно.

Comment: @Denis, добавьте то что у вас имеется и люди поймут где вы застряли и чем вам помочь :)

Comment: Сейчас уже удалось вычленить все строки с суммами через проверку на содержание в них слова "руб". Далее из этих строк пытаюсь убрать лишние символы, теги. Пока на этом засел. Код сейчас добавлю.

Comment: подсмотрел немного про вычленение цифр в других темах, вычленил. Выходит пока вот такой результат: 288
160;000
00
188
160;800
00
162
160;000
00
250
160;000
00
142
160;800
00
282
160;000
00
240
160;000
00

Comment: осталось как то убрать последовательности " 160;", которые в коде HTML судя по всему отвечают за разделение на регистры нулей (пробелы)

Comment: точнее вот такая последовательность в коде HTML идет: &#160;

Answer (score 1):

Я разбил каждую строку вот так:

```
s1.split(",|руб.|&#160;|<[^>]*>");
```

А потом все собрал обратно в строку.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
  URL u = new URL("https://market.otc.ru/ProductRequestGroup/Index/533468");
  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()))) {
    while (reader.ready()) {
      String s = reader.readLine();
      if (s.contains("руб")) {
         s = String.join("", Arrays.asList(s.split(",|руб.|&#160;|<[^>]*>"))).trim();
         min = Math.min(min, Long.parseLong(s));
      }
    }
  }
  System.out.println(min/100.);
}
```

---

Вывод:

```
142800.0
```

Comment: Крутяк! А как сделать чтобы прога постоянно после запуска отслеживала и выводила в реальном времени текущее значение? Допустим появится новое предложение и соответсвенно новый минимум и в консоли сразу сумма должна измениться.

Comment: @Denis https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html